# How to calculate quantiles?

Tags: self-study, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

Could someone please show(!) and explain step-by-step how to calculate the theoretical quantiles for the following normally distributed dataset:

{1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5,8,14,24,40}

Given this table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6lSb.jpg

EDIT: I am looking for the numbers at the bottom. The original "question": https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSohT.jpg

Comment: These are the theoretical quantiles.

Comment: Why do you need the data for the theoretical quantiles? Also, I would accept any bet that these data are not from a normal distribution. At the very least, they are rounded.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Those numbers are from slides provided by my university, stating those are normally distributed

Comment: Which book? Can you state the complete question? Also, please add the self study tag

Comment: @ChristophHanck I can't refer to slides provided by my university which aren't publicly available. Unless I put them online myself... Is this necessary? This is the complete question.

Comment: Are you certain this exercise is not about computing *sample* quantiles?

Comment: @JohnK, I edited my question

Comment: This example is to illustrate via a qq plot that this sample is most likely not from a normal distribution...! The next slide likely gives a picture showing a series departing from the 45 degree line?

Comment: @ChristophHanck, Indeed but I would like to know how to get those values at the bottom.

Comment: See my answer. Please edit your question - the sample values reported there then are indeed irrelevant for your question if you are interested in the theoretical quantiles from the slide.

Answer (score 2):

These (indeed - see comments) are theoretical quantiles of the normal distribution for different $\alpha_j$. These are the values such that $\alpha_j$ of the probability mass of a standard normally distributed random variable is to the left of that value.

The reported quantiles are following:

```
> round(pnorm(c(-1.73,-1.15,-.81,-.55,-.32,-.1,.1,.32,.55,.81,1.15,1.73)),3)
 [1] 0.042 0.125 0.209 0.291 0.374 0.460 0.540 0.626 0.709 0.791 0.875 0.958
```

So, this for example means that $-1.73$ is the 4.2%-quantile of the standard normal distribution, the value such that smaller realizations from a standard normal distribution will occur with probability 4.2%.

They are "equally spaced" (evenredig verdeeld) in the sense that there is a roughly constant amount of probability mass between each pair of neighboring quantiles:

```
> round(diff(x),3)
 [1] 0.083 0.084 0.082 0.083 0.086 0.080 0.086 0.083 0.082 0.084 0.083
```

As the cdf of the standard normal is not available in closed form, calculating these values by hand is not possible and numerical approximations are used.